# Consulta con php

Tags: php, mysql

Debo hacer un reporte de inventarios que tiene aprox 150 mil registros el punto es que cuando soliciot el reporte el server truena, intente poner ini_set('memory_limit', '1024') al inicio de mi script cuando eran menos regitros tardaba un poco pero mostraba el inventario, ¿que me recomiendan hacer?, he leido que se puede cambiar el 1024 por -1 para poner la memoria ilimitada en ese script, pero nada recomendable.
Gracias, saludos

Comment: ¿O sea, quieres mostrar 150.000 registros en una página web?  ¿Es eso?

Comment: Sugiero que hagas paginaciones con limites.  mostraras al cliente todos los registros seccionados.

Comment: Bueno aqui hay muchas variables. ¿Que libreria estas usando? normalmente tienen un metodo chunk para amortiguar el consumo de memoria.

Comment: No sabemos qué está pasando y podrían ser muchas cosas. Una importante es evitar el uso de *fetch-[all]* (nativo o PDO) en consultas con gran cantidad de resultados. Mejor usar `while` con su respectivo *fetch-[assoc][array]*

Comment: No son para mostrarlas en la pagina, son para enviarlas a un reporte pdf para esto uso la libreria FPDF

Comment: es por ello la importancia de plasmar secciones de códigos y librerías que utilizas, como mencionan los moderadores anteriores. segun analizo el problema suponiendo que son 150,000 hay que seccionar aproximadamente + de 3000 paginas, deberias analizar que la consulta directamente quiza no haya problema ahi si no el convertir tanto dato en pdf?. has intentado consultar los 150,000 registros en la BD y truena?

Comment: ¿Has mirado este script que teoricamente es para optimizar el problema que tienes? http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=76  No se si arreglará algo, pero te puede dar ideas supongo para eso del FPDF que estas usando.

Comment: @Dubio, sería optiomo que busques el mensaje de error, ya sea en los logs de Apache o en el error_log de PHP. Puede que el problema no sea de memoria, sino por tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Me uno a la sugerencia de @Marcos, conviene que revises tu log de errores. Si no sabes cómo hacerlo es bueno que investigues, pues revisar los logs te ayuda a conocer el problema con precisión ahorrándote muchísimo tiempo. Una forma rápida de mostrar los errores sería agregando esto al inicio de tu script: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` pero no lo consideres una forma definitiva de depuración, es mejor revisar los logs. Por otra parte, convendría que este tipo de código, que suele ser muy costoso,  ...

Comment: ... lo programes a un nivel más bajo, por ejemplo, mediante un script en el sistema operativo directamente.